# When and why we use next_by_code()?

Tags: odoo-13

I want to know When and why we use **next_by_code()**?
I have seen it in sales module. In sale.py file, it is written as:

```
 seq_date = fields.Datetime.context_timestamp(self, fields.Datetime.to_datetime(vals['date_order']))
            if 'company_id' in vals:
                vals['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].with_context(force_company=vals['company_id']).next_by_code(
                    'sale.order', sequence_date=seq_date) or _('New')
```

Can you guys explain it for me?
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ir.sequence` contains sequences. You can see them in the Odoo when you go Settings > Technical > Sequences (Debug mode may be needed).
Your code just asks new code for the SO.

Comment: yeah i know ir.sequence contains sequences but i need to know when and why we use next_by_code() method?

Comment: Each time you need new code. Like when you create new SO

Comment: When? Creating new record, process workflow. Why? To give unique identifier of the record

Comment: This code is defined by business needs. So the rules can be changed if needed..

Comment: Understood. Thanks Alot